# how to compare value in python

Tags: python

I am new to python, here I am getting values (0, 1) from a server response, how to use this in assertTrue in python.

```
  ret = (0, 1)  // (0, 1) this is response getting from server
  self.assertTrue(ret  == '(0, 1)')  // is this right way to do?
```

Comment: You do it the same way you did it to assign it: `self.assertTure(ret == (0,1))`.

Comment: What exactly do you get from server (i.e. what type)? Is it really a tuple? Do you process the server response to get this tuple? Post [mre]

Comment: Also note in python we use `#` for comments, not `//`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the response from the server is a tuple, you could test it with a simple test case as follows:

```py
import unittest

response = (0, 1)
  
class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # Returns True or False. 
    def test(self):        
        self.assertTrue((response == (0, 1)), "The response is not (0, 1)")
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If it is not a tuple but a string that you receive, you could change the value in the assertTrue condition from `(0, 1)` to `"(0, 1)"`.

Please refer to the [documentation on unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) for more details.

If you don't want to use `unittest`, but you do want to make sure that the response is correct, you could also use the `assert` statement (however, there might be better ways to check this):

```py
response = (0, 1)
assert(response == (0, 1)) # This will do nothing

assert(response == (1, 1)) # This results in an AssertionError
```

Due to the `AssertionError` your program will stop. If you don't want this, you could use a `try-except` block:

```py
response = (0, 1)
  
try:
    assert(response == (0, 1))
except AssertionError:
    print("The response is not correct.")
```

### EDIT:

As the response you are receiving is of type `MQTTMessageInfo`, you want to compare against this. I didn't find much documentation on this type, but you can see [what the class looks like on Github](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L297).

Here, you can see the response you are seeing is a string representation of the following:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return str((self.rc, self.mid))
```

The first value in `(0, 1)` is the `self.rc` and the second is `self.mid`. If you only want to assert that these two values are indeed correct, you can modify the test case above to something like this:

```py
self.assertTrue((response.rc == 0 and response.mid == 1)), "The MQTTMessageInfo is not rc=0, and mid=1")
```

Comment: print((res))
print(type(res))

(0, 1)
<class 'paho.mqtt.client.MQTTMessageInfo'>

Comment: I don't know much about this `Eclipse Paho MQTT Python Client` specifically, but I have updated my answer with what I was able to understand by looking at their GitHub. Hopefully that helps.